# Yarn Install fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get in to reactjs first I install the create-react-app using npm and once I run the create-react-app command it was throwing me the following error

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '-g',
0 verbose cli   'yarn'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Thilina\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-30T07_44_49_903Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 27ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
29 timing idealTree:init Completed in 6ms
30 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
31 silly idealTree buildDeps
32 silly fetch manifest yarn@*
33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn 874ms (cache miss)
34 silly placeDep ROOT yarn@1.22.18 OK for:  want: *
35 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 887ms
36 timing idealTree:node_modules/yarn Completed in 0ms
37 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 888ms
38 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
39 timing idealTree Completed in 899ms
40 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 901ms
41 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
42 silly reify moves {}
43 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
44 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 1ms
45 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
46 silly audit bulk request { yarn: [ '1.22.18' ] }
47 silly tarball no local data for yarn@https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.18.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
48 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 445ms
49 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 446ms
50 silly audit report {}
51 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
52 timing reify:audit Completed in 446ms
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.18.tgz 3096ms (cache miss)
54 timing reifyNode:node_modules/yarn Completed in 3103ms
55 timing reify:unpack Completed in 3104ms
56 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
57 timing build:queue Completed in 5ms
58 info run yarn@1.22.18 preinstall node_modules/yarn :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
59 info run yarn@1.22.18 preinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
60 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 6ms
61 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
62 timing command:install Completed in 8818ms
63 verbose stack Error: command failed
63 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
63 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
63 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
63 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
63 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
63 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
64 verbose pkgid yarn@1.22.18
65 verbose cwd F:\ReactNative\React\ReactWithMosh
66 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
67 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yarn"
68 verbose node v16.15.0
69 verbose npm  v8.5.5
70 error code 1
71 error path C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
72 error command failed
73 error command bash -c :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
74 verbose exit 1
75 timing npm Completed in 9221ms
76 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1653896690302
77 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1653896694324
78 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1653896694324
79 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1653896694324
80 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:preinstall 1653896694329
81 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:preinstall:node_modules/yarn 1653896694330
82 verbose code 1
83 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
83 error     C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-30T07_44_49_903Z-debug-0.log
```

So, I searched the internet and found that there's a temporary workaround using installing yarn
so, I tried to install yarn and I ran the following command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and I get the following error

Any help would be highly appreciated

I've tried cleaning cache using -force but still won't work.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '-g',
0 verbose cli   'yarn'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Thilina\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-30T07_44_49_903Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 27ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
29 timing idealTree:init Completed in 6ms
30 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
31 silly idealTree buildDeps
32 silly fetch manifest yarn@*
33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn 874ms (cache miss)
34 silly placeDep ROOT yarn@1.22.18 OK for:  want: *
35 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 887ms
36 timing idealTree:node_modules/yarn Completed in 0ms
37 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 888ms
38 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
39 timing idealTree Completed in 899ms
40 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 901ms
41 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
42 silly reify moves {}
43 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
44 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 1ms
45 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
46 silly audit bulk request { yarn: [ '1.22.18' ] }
47 silly tarball no local data for yarn@https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.18.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
48 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 445ms
49 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 446ms
50 silly audit report {}
51 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
52 timing reify:audit Completed in 446ms
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.18.tgz 3096ms (cache miss)
54 timing reifyNode:node_modules/yarn Completed in 3103ms
55 timing reify:unpack Completed in 3104ms
56 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
57 timing build:queue Completed in 5ms
58 info run yarn@1.22.18 preinstall node_modules/yarn :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
59 info run yarn@1.22.18 preinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
60 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 6ms
61 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
62 timing command:install Completed in 8818ms
63 verbose stack Error: command failed
63 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
63 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
63 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
63 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
63 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
63 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
64 verbose pkgid yarn@1.22.18
65 verbose cwd F:\ReactNative\React\ReactWithMosh
66 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
67 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yarn"
68 verbose node v16.15.0
69 verbose npm  v8.5.5
70 error code 1
71 error path C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
72 error command failed
73 error command bash -c :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
74 verbose exit 1
75 timing npm Completed in 9221ms
76 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1653896690302
77 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1653896694324
78 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1653896694324
79 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1653896694324
80 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:preinstall 1653896694329
81 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:preinstall:node_modules/yarn 1653896694330
82 verbose code 1
83 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
83 error     C:\Users\Thilina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-30T07_44_49_903Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I managed to fix the react Install issue with the following command

```bash
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

error occurs because of a post install script trying to run and it fails to find bash